# What is a circuit?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, fft

The book *Algorithms* demonstrates the Fast Fourier Transform through a "circuit", using "wires" to carry data. What is a circuit? Is it simply a concept made up by the author of the book to better demonstrate the algorithm or is it a recognized computer science concept?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but Google circuit computer science and you get a Wikiepdia page with the answer.

Comment: ...but there appear to be almost no questions on circuit complexity on Stack Overflow, so I withdraw my flippant remark.

Comment: This question might be better served on [cs.se].  Circuits are an academic sort of subject, not a software engineering one.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I'm obviously familiar with the electronics version of a circuit. I do have a strong foundation in electronics. I was specifically asking about the computer science circuit's application in demonstrating theories, not the common electronic one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is, yes, "circuits" are a recognized concept in theoretical computer science, drawing on the related concept from electronics.  A Boolean circuit is basically what it sounds like:  A model for computation over binary strings, consisting of boolean logic gates strung together with wires.  You can find a formal definition [here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit) at Wikipedia.

Where they come in handy is, as you've seen, determining complexity of a particular problem.  The FFT example is fairly accessible, but probably the most famous example is Cook's definition of NP-Completeness, which turns on the proof that determining whether a given Boolean circuit is satisfiable is NP-Complete.

Barrington and Maciel have a series of computation complexity [lecture notes](http://people.clarkson.edu/~alexis/PCMI/) that introduce circuits in the first lecture and continue to use the concept throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems are easy, and some are hard.  In order to say what makes a problem easy and what makes it hard with more rigger, we use generally models of computer and place constraints on those models.

[Turing Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machines) are one common model used to define classes of problems.  For example, the complexity class **P** comprises problems such that there exists a Turing Machine that can solve the problem in O(n^p) time for some power p (polynomial time).  We can get other complexity classes with other constraints on time or space bounds on the Turing Machine.

[Non-deterministic Turing Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine) are another model for computers.  [Alternating Turing machines are another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_Turing_machine).  Many models for computers exist, and each are useful for defining different types of problems.  [Circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_%28computer_theory%29) are one of these models of computers.

Turing machines useful for modeling single-threaded computer programs.  Circuits shine when modeling massively parallel computations.  For example, Nick's class or **NC** comprise problems that can be solved "quickly" (poly-log time) with a polynomial number of processors.

Comment: I just realized as I was writing that answer that you were talking about a Fast FFT.  I dimly recall some diagrams with circuits involved in explaining that algorithm, but don't recall how they relate to the circuits I wrote about.  There will probably be people on [cs.se] that have forgotten dozens of times more about this sort of thing than I ever knew.